# what is the right code to use php execution header

Tags: php, execution

I have this line in my execution script

```
$Headers = "From: ".$_POST['fname']." <support@domain.com> \r\n" .
```

and it works fine.

I have tried in several ways to call up the user email address to replace support@... but all my effort failed.

I have tried this code

```
$Headers = "From: ".$_POST['fname']." <".$_POST['email']."> \r\n" .
```

Comment: It should work if `$_POST['email']` is a valid email address.

Comment: What does `var_dump($Headers)` show after you do that?

Comment: @Barmar, it worked.....I didn't notice that

Comment: is it possible to delete this question?

Comment: Not once someone has posted an answer. Flag it for closure.

Comment: I was making reference to the old email sent. The new one just delivered and it was correct. Thank you all for your assistance.